# Retrieve row number of clicked cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How can I get row number as result of a clicked cell? For example, if I click on cell `C9`, then I need the function to return `9` as answer.

Comment: Where do you see the result?  In another cell in the spreadsheet?

Comment: What do you mean 'Computer Software based on MS Excel'? Are you trying to make a program to output the clicked cell? Because, then that would mean this is off-topic...

Answer (score 1):

- Open up Excel.
- Open up the VBA editor (Alt-F11).
- In the Project pane, double click the sheet you want to apply this to.
- In the code window that opens, input the following:

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
>     MsgBox ActiveCell.Row
> End Sub
> ```

- Close the VBA editor.
- Now as you click/move around to different cells it will popup a dialog box telling you the current cell's row.
- You could assign the results to a variable instead of using a MsgBox if you need to use the value someplace else.

Additionally/Alternatively you could create your own function that actually returns the row when referenced...  Something like:

```
 Public Function MyCustomSub() As Integer
     MyCustomSub = ActiveCell.Row
 End Function

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
     MsgBox MyCustomSub()
 End Sub
```

This should be plenty of info to help provide you with options to accomplish exactly what you're aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Techie007 points out, the easiest way would be through a macro, but I have a feeling you do not need things to be that advanced. Here's the easiest way.

EDIT:
You can use the ROW() function to get the current row's number.

OBSOLETE (tnx Scott):

Use a column (or insert it anywhere). Lets assume you'll use column A.

Select Cell A1.

Enter value 1 in the cell.

Select the cell again (you probably pressed enter, and are in the cell below it).

At the bottom right of that selected cell, there's this small square. Drag it down as much as necessary. It will create a list of numbers starting from 1, then 2, then 3, etc...

Now in your other cells, you can use a formula to refer to these cells to get the rownumber.

You can then give Column A a width of 0 pixels, and it will be invisible yet the values can still be retreived.

Comment: I’m not sure what the question is, but I’m doubly unsure how this could be the answer. Are you saying, “Set `A1` to `1`, `A2` to `2`, and so on, so cell `Q42` can get its row number by accessing `$A42` (which will contain `42`).”? That’s unnecessarily complicated; cell `Q42` can get its row number by calling `ROW()`.

Comment: Ah how stupid of me. Of cource... the row() function.